# why someone change my file in hosting easily?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, security, cpanel

I used CodeIgniter to build website. This day my file on website is changed and my home page show:

```
hacked by sayaculun7 N1ced4y@yahoo.com
```

I don't know why it can change my file even I change password of cPanel and change to original file it still change it again and generate new files.

Question:

1 - Why someone can change my file in hosting easily?

2 - Does it from file and folder permission?

3 - Can htaccess protect it?

Comment: This isn't really a programming queston... it might be better off on Web Masters http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or Server Fault http://serverfault.com/

Comment: they can change your files easily because the password was hacked and they gained FTP or Cpanel details. You will need to check to make sure no other files have been modified or they may still be able to gain access through a backdoor

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

1. Because either there are vulnerabilities in your site, you let your password be compromised, or they brute-forced your password.
2. Usually not, no.
3. .htaccess has no "Don't hack this" directive you can use, but it is possible to use .htaccess to restrict access to sensitive locations, or add an extra layer of password protection.

My usual suggestions for general site security are:

1. Keep your site software up to date.
2. Use strong passwords.
3. Implement CAPTCHA on all login/signup screens.
4. Don't give your password to strangers, or install malware on your local computer.
5. Don't save backup files to web-accessible folders.

Since it's already broken, I'd suggest contacting your Hosting company to see if they can identify and plug the hole. They may not be able to reverse the damage, but most will at least remove any malware and change all your passwords for you.

Comment: Thank you @Sintrinsic, for your suggestions 2, 3, 4, 5 i have used it and for 1 in up to my hosting provider. But i still have hacked. I appreciate you suggestions. And the next step i need to learn how to hack too to protect my website